# Google recaptcha V3 check score

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

i implemented the v3 recaptcha like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newsletterForm').jqBootstrapValidation().on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      } else {
        // everything looks good!
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.execute();
      }
    });
});
```

and my submit looks like this:

```
function onSubmit(token){
        document.getElementById("newsletterForm").submit();
};
```

And when i open the site with a bot client it works how it should i have to click the pictures, but i still get many spam registration so i thought i can adjust the "score" but i've no idea where and how cause google gives no explanation for that.

Hope you can help me, ty!

Comment: Did you [verify the token](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site_verify_response)?

Comment: i updated the question i think the onSubmit(token) does that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "did you verify the token on the server-side"?

Comment: Yes i do and validates correctly i can't submit with my "google robot" device but with my normal devices i can.